# Cannot delete temp folder (sometimes)

Tags: java, io

When I start my application I create a temp folder:

```
  public static File createTempDir(String name) throws IOException {
    File tempDir = File.createTempFile(name, "");
    if (!(tempDir.delete())) {
      throw new IOException("could not delete" + tempDir.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    if (!(tempDir.mkdir())) {
      throw new IOException("could not create" + tempDir.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    tempDir.deleteOnExit();
    return tempDir;
  }
```

During a session a user might load a file. As a result the old temp dir is deleted and a new is created based on the ID of the file loaded.

During load where the old temp dir is deleted I sometimes get a:

java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file:

Here is how the old temp folder is deleted:

```
  public void cleanup(String tmpPath) {
    File tmpFolder = new File(tmpPath);
    if (tmpFolder != null && tmpFolder.isDirectory()) {
      try {
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(file);
      } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } 
  }
```

where FileUtils is: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils. Typically the content of the temp folder is:

mytempfolder_uuid
   |-> mysubfolder
          |-> myImage.jpg

And the error is:

java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\mytempfolder_uuid\mysubfolder\myImage.jpg

I have tried to debug the application and before the delete operation is executed verified that the above image is actually located in the specified folder.

The nasty thing is that it only happens sometimes. I have made sure not to have the folder/files in the temp folder open in any other applications. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to close the stream to that file somewhere in your application?

Comment: maybe someone(user,application) use that folder sometimes when you try to delete.

Comment: @tul, you have almost 30 questions without an accepted answer.  Perhaps you can try asking questions which can reasonably be answered or follow up answers so they can be accepted. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use the Guava library. It has a method [`Files.createTempDir()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#createTempDir%28%29) that does exactly what you seem to need:

> Atomically creates a new directory somewhere beneath the system's
>   temporary directory (as defined by the java.io.tmpdir system
>   property), and returns its name. Use this method instead of
>   File.createTempFile(String, String) when you wish to create a
>   directory, not a regular file. **A common pitfall is to call
>   createTempFile, delete the file and create a directory in its place,
>   but this leads a race condition which can be exploited to create
>   security vulnerabilities, especially when executable files are to be
>   written into the directory.** This method assumes that the temporary
>   volume is writable, has free inodes and free blocks, and that it will
>   not be called thousands of times per second.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip will give it a try! I really need this to be deterministic. Currently it only works sometimes even though I go through the exact same steps (save/load the same folders/files) seems very random.

Comment: Ok I have tried to replace the my implementation with the guava one but my problem persist. For some reason a file (image.jpg) in the temp dir cannot be deleted half the times I run the test - the other half it works fine. Must be some resource has it or its not disposed correctly before deleted.

Comment: @tul yes, make sure you close all streams (in and out) in finally blocks. You might want to look at [`Closeables`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closeables.html) for that.

Comment: Basically I just set an org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.Image on a button like:  myImage = new Image(getDisplay(), new ImageData(absolutePath));
          button.setImage(myImage); Before doing the load I make sure to the container widget is closed and all sub widgets/images are disposed. But what still bother me is that it only occurs with a 50% chance.

Comment: @tul can't help you with SWT. You should ask that part in another question with the SWT tag

Answer (score 5):

You cannot delete files which are open and you can't delete a directory which contains a file. You have to ensure all files in the directory are closed.

Comment: As I understand org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(file) deletes a folder recursively. Is it possible from java code to get a list of processes that has a reference to specific file/folder?

Comment: You can in Unix with `lsof`. It is more than likely it is your process which has the files open. esp if they are temporary files.

Answer (score 1):

try deleting the files in the temp folder before deleting it. Try somethng like

```
private boolean deleteFolder(File path) {
    if (path.exists()) {
        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                deleteFolder(f);
            } else {
                f.delete();
            }
        }
    }

    return path.delete();
}
```

also using deleteOnExit is not a very good idea...

cheers!

Comment: But thats exactly what org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(file) does. An I need the deleteOnExit since I don't want the temp dir to grow insanely large - how would you else perform a cleanup?

Comment: deleteOnExit won't help you keep the temp dir to a minimal size.
If you want to do this you can write a simple thread that monitors the dirs size and deletes it if the size passes a certain threshold. Or if you are using apache commons you can install a FileMonitor to watch the directory...

using deleteOnExit is bad, as it can leak memory and it does not guarantee that it will succeed.

Comment: yeah it seems that deleteOnExit only works for empty folders :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean deleteDir(String path)
{
    java.io.File dir = new java.io.File(path);
    if (dir.isDirectory())
    {
        String[] filesList = dir.list();
        for(String s : filesList)
        {
            boolean success = new java.io.File(dir, s).delete();
            if(!success)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
```

and then you can use it like: `deleteDir("C:\\MyFolder\\subFolder\\")`

Comment: I believe this is basically what org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(file) does.